# I want to refetch query by clicking buttons. But It doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query, tanstackreact-query

```
export const useLogin = (loginType) => {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ['login', loginType],
    // 'login' is simple function which use axios get method
    queryFn: async () => await login(loginType),
  });
};

const Login = () => {
  const [loginType, setLoginType] = useState('google');

  const { data } = useLogin(loginType);

  const onClickSocialLogin = (type) => {
    setLoginType(type);

    // I want to use data
  };
  
  return (
    <button onClick={() => onClickSocialLogin('google')}>Google Login</button>
    <button onClick={() => onClickSocialLogin('github')}>Github Login</button>
  )
}
```

When I click Google Login button, I want to use google login data in onClickSocialLogin function.
When I click Github Login button, I want to use github login data in onClickSocialLogin function.
But When I use data in onClickSocialLogin funtion, this data is old one. How can I fix it??

Comment: *"When I use data in onClickSocialLogin funtion, this data is old one."* - What specifically are you referring to in this case?  The only thing `onClickSocialLogin` does is update state to the value passed to it.  Are you saying that, when the component re-renders, the value passed to `useLogin` is not updated, and `data` doesn't change?  Something else?  What specific problem are you observing and where/how specifically are you observing it?

Comment: @David
console.log data after `const { data } = useLogin(loginType);` => this works,
but console.log data after `setLoginType(type);` => this logs old data. I want to use new data after `setLoginType(type);`

Comment: It's worth noting that nowhere in the code shown are you logging anything to the console.  But for the *described* console logs that makes sense.  `data` won't be updated until the component re-renders.  There's no reason to expect its assignment to have changed (and an assignment to a `const` *can't* change) without having re-executed the line of code which assigns it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: Although it's a GET API call, the request could be better handled with the useMutation of react-query. One benefit is that it exposes its onSuccess callback. Another is that I don't think you should be caching the login result. Also as per the code example, you are nowhere using the { data }. It's better to rely on useMutation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login should be `mutation`. It logs the user in, or creates a token. You don't want to cache it. It's also likely a POST request, so it's a mutation.

Mutations don't have the problem because you can just fire them imperatively:

```
export const useLogin = (loginType, onSuccess) => {
  return useMutation({
    mutationFn: login
  });
}

const { mutate } = useLogin()

<button onClick={() => mutate('google')}>Google Login</button>
<button onClick={() => mutate('github')}>Github Login</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing is due to the asynchronous nature of the useQuery hook from React Query. When you call setLoginType(type), it updates the state and triggers a re-render. However, the data fetched by useQuery is not immediately available because the query is asynchronous. Thus, when you try to use data in the onClickSocialLogin function, it still holds the old data from the previous state.

To solve this, you can use the onSuccess callback provided by useQuery. This callback is executed when the query successfully fetches new data. Here's how you can modify your useLogin hook and Login component:

Modified useLogin Hook

```
export const useLogin = (loginType, onSuccess) => {
return useQuery({
queryKey: ['login', loginType],
queryFn: async () => await login(loginType),
onSuccess: onSuccess,
});
};
```

The login component:

```
 const Login = () => {
 const [loginType, setLoginType] = useState('google');

 const onSuccess = (newData) => {
// newData contains the latest data fetched by useQuery
// You can use newData here as per your requirement
 };

 const { data } = useLogin(loginType, onSuccess);

 const onClickSocialLogin = (type) => {
  setLoginType(type);

   // Instead of using 'data' here, use it in the 'onSuccess' callback
  };

   return (
       <>
     <button onClick={() => onClickSocialLogin('google')}>Google 
      Login</button>
      <button onClick={() => onClickSocialLogin('github')}>Github 
      Login</button>
      </>
    );
    }
```

This approach ensures that you have the latest data available in the onSuccess callback. You can handle the new data accordingly based on the type of login or any other logic you need. Remember, the onSuccess callback is only triggered after the new data is successfully fetched, so you won't be dealing with stale data.

Comment: can't use onSuccess in v5